# Firebase Firestore onSnapshot PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large on Expo / React Native project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have Expo / React Native project that subscribes to listen Firestore collection updates. I updated Expo SDK from 39 to 40 and  onSnapshot callback function started to throw 'PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large' when it gets called.  I have not updated documents in collection nor I have changed code.  Firebase version is, "firebase": "7.9.0" and I didn't update it when upgrading Expo SDK.

**Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix?**

I subscribe to collection updates like this

```
  componentDidMount = () => {

//Subscribe for collection changes
const unSubscribeUpdates = this.unsubscribe = db.collection("test_collection")
.onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: false}, this.onTestCollectionChanged).bind(this);
 
//Subscribe for favourite changes
const unSubscribeFavouriteUpdates = this.unsubscribe = db.collection("favourites")
.doc(Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
.onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: false},this.onFavouritesChanged).bind(this);

this.setState({ collection_items: items, favourites:favourites, unSubscribeUpdates: unSubscribeUpdates, unSubscribeFavouriteUpdates:unSubscribeFavouriteUpdates });
```

and listeners are like this

```
  onFavouritesListChanged = (doc) => {
    console.log("onFavouritesListChanged for user :" + Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
.....

  onVideoListChanged = (snapshot) => {
    console.log("onVideoListChanged");
    console.log("videos length " + this.state.videos.length);
```

This is the error

> > onVideoListChanged
> > PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
> > at readStream (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
> > at getRawBody (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
> > at read (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
> > at jsonParser (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:135:5)
> > at call (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
> > at next (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
> > at serveStatic (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
> > at call (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
> > at next (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
> > at call (/Users/nnn/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:248:3)

Comment: It sounds like you have a bug report for expo, not a programming problem for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that this was not issue in Expo but instead in NodeJs 14 when printing too long string into console.log output.

Answer (score 1):

It is the warning of the cnosole.log output